# file with main calls a function in the other file and then returns

Tags: c

getting multiple definition of `sqrtof2' error. im trying to get one c program to get square root of 2 from another c program. then using a makefile to bring them togeher. so lost

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include "make2.c"


    int  main(void) {

        double num =2.0;
        // calls the sqrt function  make2.c

        sqrtof2(num);

        printf("The sqaure root: %f", num);


        return(0);
    }


2nd program: make2.c


    #include <stdio.h>

    #include <math.h>

    sqrtof2 (double  num4) {
    double num5 = 0;
    num5= sqrt(num4);

    return num5;

}


makeupfile: make3.h
#ifndef TEST_H_INCLUDED
#define TEST_H_INCLUDED


    void sqrtof2(void);

#endif
```

Comment: Why are you doing this -  #include "make2.c"  ? remove that.  make2.c will be compiled into a seprate object file which you should then link with your main c file.

Comment: Why are you trying to use separate files? Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do `"#include <math.h>"` and `"#include <stdio.h>"` in your make2.c file because they are already included in your main file, and your main file is including the make2.c file. This should get rid of your error, although we would have to see the exact contents of your Makefile in order to properly diagnose what might be happening. At the very least, you should have additional warnings about implicit declarations.

Update: the way you are doing this program is not the best. You should use header files to specify the prototypes for functions that are included in separate files and then link individual object files together in the main program.

Update 2: Someone requested for me to actually compile your files, so I put your first program into `make1.c` and your second program into `make2.c`. With no Makefile needed, I can simply type `make make1` and I get a working program `make1` with no compilation errors... but which produces the wrong answer, of course (2 instead of 1.4...).

As pointed out in one of the other answers, there is a lot more wrong with the program than just multiple declarations. You are not using the value returned from your `sqrtof2` function at all.

If you want to calculate the square root of `num` *and* store the result back into `num` as it seems like you want to do, then you need to say `num = sqrtof2(num);`

But of course, that still produces the wrong answer.

The reason is that your function is implicitly being set to return an integer value. You need to place `double` in front of the function's declaration, i.e., `double sqrtof2 (double  num4)`

But when you type `make make1` again, then nothing will happen. You start to find out the problem with including a `.c` file inside of another C file. The `make` program cannot detect that the source code of make1.c depends on the updated contents of make2.c, and you have to type `touch make1.c` (or edit make1.c) and then type `make make1` again in order to produce a working executable version of make1 which produces your desired answer of 1.414214...

So follow the excellent advice of some of the other answers about how to structure your program. :)

Comment: I didn't downvote. But, your answer should not encourage the asker to include a `.c` file in another `.c` file.

Comment: @jxh right on, I changed my answer to talk more about the problem rather than just fixing the symptoms.

Comment: The C standard mandates that including a standard header multiple times will not cause a problem (it will be the same as if it had only included once).

Comment: If you try the program yourself, you'll see that you would have a hard time duplicating the asker's symptom. The asker must have generated two `.o` files, one for each `.c` file. So your suggestion in the first line will not fix the asker's problem.

Comment: The problem is the lack of an assignment on the "call" in the main file. That's why the error is multiple definition of **sqrtof2**. Of course there are lots of other problems, but that's the immediate link error.

Comment: @bitfiddler That doesn't produce an error for me in my actual compilation of these files. Of course, we have no idea what strange way the Makefile might be set up, and the error might be caused by an incorrect Makefile. We would have to know what actual compilation commands are being issued in order to diagnose what went wrong for sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can compile it (I've added some clarifying comments):

The main file `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "make2.h" /* we include the header containing sqrtof2 */

int  main(void)
{

    double num = 2.0;
    // calls the sqrt function

    printf("The square root: %f", sqrtof2(num)); /* I've moved the call to sqrtof2 here so that it will print the proper answer */


    return 0;
}
```

The source file where we define `sqrtof2` `make2.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "make2.h" /* note that we include the header where sqrtof2 is declared so we can define it here */

double sqrtof2 (double  num4) /* note the return type and function parameters as they were incorrect in the header */
{
    double num5 = 0;
    num5= sqrt(num4);

    return num5;

}
```

Finally the header where `sqrtof2` is declared `make2.h`:

```
#ifndef TEST_H_INCLUDED
#define TEST_H_INCLUDED


double sqrtof2(double  num4); /* I've changed the function signature to match that of the implementation file */

#endif
```

Finally to compile it, I just call the following (where `-lm` is used to link to `math.h`):

```
gcc main.c make2.c -lm
```

And voila! Everything compiles without warnings.

Comment: Hahaha, thanks, I thought that OP had it almost right save for a few inaccuracies so tried to reuse his code as much as I could.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your function to return `double`:

```
double sqrtof2 (double  num4) {
    double num5 = 0;
    num5= sqrt(num4);

    return num5;
}
```

Otherwise, the compiler will assume it returned `int`.

You should use a header file instead of `#include "make2.c"`

Answer (score 0):

Create a make2.h file that contains just the function declaration of `sqrtof2 (double  num4)`
and include that .h file instead of make2.c in your main file.

include essentially copies the content of the included file into the including file.  You are getting the error because the sqrtof2 function is being defined twice, once in make2.c and again in main when the .c file is included

Answer (score 0):

Your code has lots of problems as others have noted, but the error that you are getting is because your call to sqrtof2(num) does not have an assignement so it looks like another declaration of the same function. You need to return the value to another variable like this:

```
double rVal = sqrtof2( num ) ;
```

And then print that as your answer.  Fix all of the other stuff too, but it won't work without this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "make.h"


int  main(void) {

    double num =2.0;
    // calls the sqrt function  make2.c
    double res = 0.0;

    res = sqrtof2(num);

    printf("The sqaure root of %f is: %f", num,res);


    return(0);
}
```

// 2nd program: make2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>

double sqrtof2(double  num4) {
double num5 = 0;
num5= sqrt(num4);

return num5;
```

}

// makeupfile: make.h
#ifndef TEST_H_INCLUDED
#define TEST_H_INCLUDED

```
double sqrtof2(double);
```

#endif